# formatting REST JSON output to another format

Tags: javascript, json

My REST service returns:

```
{
items: [2]
0:  {
Label: "iPad Simulator:iOS:iPad Simulator x86_64"
Value: 14
}-
1:  {
Label: "android"
Value: 6
}-
-
count: 2
hasMore: false
limit: 5
offset: 0
-
}
```

However, my ui js component expects it in the format

```
[ {
    label : "iPad Simulator:iOS:iPad Simulator x86_64",
    value : 14
  }, {
    label : "android",
    value : 6
  } ];
```

any advise on how to achieve that other than manually going into the structure and create another one based on my desired format

Comment: modify your rest servce. the first is not a valid json. can we see the service code. you got more of them details?

Comment: Why are you not returning valid JSON from your REST service?

Comment: I am using Oracle ADF REST generation feature. which is generating it this way.  I could nt find options to modify it the way i need it

Comment: Are you sure that's what the raw response actually looks like?

Comment: yes thats how it looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so my actual problem was that the response was containg my data wrapped in Object for each row. i had to convert it manually as

```
   arr = '';
                for(var x in donutData){
                  arr = arr.concat('{label:"' + donutData[x].Label + '",value:'+ donutData[x].Value + '},');
                }

               arr = arr.substring(0, arr.length-1);
                donutData  = '[' + arr + ']';

             }
```